# How to exchange code for access token with oauth2 using nuxt/auth-next

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I am using `"@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1618898588.9655d0e"` for the authentication and I want to integrate google using it.
I have setup following code in nuxt.config.js

```js
google: {
  clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_LATEST,
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/account/login',
  responseType: 'code',
  accessType: 'offline',
  grantType: 'authorization_code',
  codeChallengeMethod: 'S256'
}
```

and in login page

```js
loginWithGoogle() {
  this.$auth.loginWith('google')
}
```

after I click on login with google, google request is made and redirected to redirectUri with query appended as `http://localhost:3000/account/login?state=3OyMNy2ODj&code=4%2F0AY0e-g6YkRJFyVCVxo8Ph2-WXpTYjKbxyuAE3r6F1PB_pt8W9QlRgdtxpEeKxfzYvX6g&scope=email%20profile%20openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=consent`

Now I need to request to google again for the access token and I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: DId you find out how? I Know how to do it manually but I was hoping this all can be done via nuxt auth!

Answer (score 0):

You need to exchange the authorization code with an access token. Along with the auth code, you'll also need to send your oauth2 client secret and client id.

Example:

```
curl -d https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>&client_secret=<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>&code=<AUTH_CODE_RECEIVED>A&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/account/login
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question it's sending for a long time, but I have this problem and I sprend a big time do fix this, it's my solution on

nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      google: {
        clientId: '81409153991-q2fm4735fcqe7fdlldo1d05k6i69n61a.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
        responseType: 'code id_token token',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
        endpoints: {
          authorization: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
          token: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
          userInfo: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
          logout: 'https://accounts.google.com/logout'
        },
        scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/callback',
      home: '/'
    }
  }
```